# How would you group multiple result in one column with a count for each result using postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I'm in a bit of a struggle right now, I've been looking all day but I haven't managed to find out how to do what I'm supposed to do.

I would like to do a view for my API using postgres (can be a function if needed)
which will show the few top players (the one who have created the most Events)

The result I'm looking for would be an output like:

```
{"nickname": "Username" , ... , "total_event_created": 12, "Events":{"eventID": 1 , "event_name":CS:go, "total": 6}, {"eventID: 2 , "event_name": lol, "total": 6}
```

First I've got my Event table like that

```
CREATE TABLE "event" (
"id" INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
"user_id" INT NOT NULL REFERENCES "user"("id"),
"game_id" INT NOT NULL REFERENCES "game"("id"),
"event_time" TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
"duration" INTERVAL ,
"player_count" INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1  CONSTRAINT max_player CHECK (player_count <= player_max),
"player_max" INT NOT NULL ,
"description" TEXT,
"status" INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
"vocal" TEXT);
```

I've tried a lot of different things using `json_agg()` but I never manage to get something right.

So far my best try is this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.user_id) "user_id" AS "_user_id",
    us.nickname AS "_name",
    us.avatar AS "_avatar",
    us.banner AS "_banner",
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user_access."event" ev WHERE us.id = ev.user_id) AS "_total_events",
    (SELECT COUNT (CASE WHEN g.id = 1 THEN 1 END) ) AS "_total_cs",
    (SELECT COUNT (CASE WHEN g.id = 2 THEN 1 END) ) AS "_total_lol"
FROM user_access."user" us
JOIN user_access."event" e  ON us.id = e.user_id 
JOIN user_access."game"  g ON  e.game_id = g.id
GROUP BY  e.user_id, us.nickname, us.id ;
```

output:

```
_user_id |   _name    |   _avatar   |   _banner   | _total_events | _total_cs | _total_lol 
----------+------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------
       1 | test1login | avatar1.png | banner1.png |             3 |         2 |          1
       2 | test2login | avatar2.png | banner2.png |             1 |         0 |          1
```

Thanks guy's for clearing my code, from what you send me i arrived to something better :

```
SELECT  us."id" AS "_user_id",
            us.nickname AS "_name",
            us.avatar AS "_avatar",
            us.banner AS "_banner",
            COUNT(DISTINCT e.id) as "_total_events",
             jsonb_build_object('cs', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE g.id = 1 ),'lol',  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE g.id = 2))  AS "_total_by_game"       
        FROM user_access."user" us 
        JOIN user_access."event" e ON us.id = e.user_id 
        JOIN user_access."game"  g ON e.game_id = g.id
    GROUP BY us.id
    ORDER BY "_total_events" DESC;
```

output:

```
 _user_id |   _name    |   _avatar   |   _banner   | _total_events |   _total_by_game    
 ----------+------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------
          1 | test1login | avatar1.png | banner1.png |          3 | {"cs": 2, "lol": 1}
          2 | test2login | avatar2.png | banner2.png |          1 | {"cs": 0, "lol": 1}
```

Comment: So, a user is involved in games by *creating events*, but also because they *have* games. How does this come into play? What shall the new result look like?

Comment: And then, you mention that you only want to show the top players having created most events. How many? Do you want to look for the maximum event number created by a user and then show all users who have created exactly this amount? Or do you want to show the top 5? (But then, what to do in case of ties?)

Comment: yeah they basicaly can register the game they play with the level they play on to display  on their profile , but the event has a set game on creation
 "game_id" INT NOT NULL REFERENCES "game"("id"),  
the player who create the event set the game he wants from the game  he has  registered

Comment: and the result would be like a top 5 or 10 from the people who participate the most on the event creation so yeah get the total amount each user has created and sort them in a way the one who created the most event is shown first (sorry for my english i'm not native so i may not be clear

Comment: Yeah, I must admit that I find it hard to follow. I don't think it's your English, though. You have written a query that counts the events a user has created. Gordon and I have shown in our answers, how to improve this query. If all you want to do is get the top 5, add `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY`. The table M_USER_has_GAME doesn't seem to have anything to do with this.

Comment: yeah i guess i wanted to put as much information to be clear and it had the opposit effect, and i was rewriting my code so much that it started to be a huge mess i have to agree,  thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your query:

1. You group by user. You do this thrice, for no apparent reason: Once by their ID, then by by their name, then by their ID again.
2. You use `DISTINCT ON` user ID. Why? The `GROUP BY` already gives you one row per user. Then with `DISTINCT ON` you say: from this one row, give me one row, no matter which (because there is no `ORDER BY` clause that you'd usually have for `DISTINCT ON`, but well, you only have one row per user anyway, so this all is just void).
3. `(SELECT COUNT (CASE WHEN g.id = 1 THEN 1 END) )` is invalid and should raise an error. It can be re-written to `CASE WHEN g.id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. But as you are aggregating per user there can be multiple g.id. Which one do you want to show? There would have to be an aggregation function for this to work, e.g. `SUM((SELECT COUNT (CASE WHEN g.id = 1 THEN 1 END)))`, which of course would again just be `SUM(CASE WHEN g.id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

It seems you just want an aggregation:

```
SELECT
  us.id AS "_user_id",
  us.nickname AS "_name",
  us.avatar AS "_avatar",
  us.banner AS "_banner",
  COUNT(*) AS "_total_events",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN g.id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS "_total_cs",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN g.id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS "_total_lol"
FROM user_access.user us
JOIN user_access.event e ON e.user_id = us.id 
JOIN user_access.game g ON g.id = e.game_id
GROUP BY us.id
```

For the top 5 add:

```
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

BTW: Do you really want to count how many events a user had in game 1 (_total_cs) and 2 (_total_lol) or is this a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT us."user_id" AS "_user_id",
       us.nickname AS "_name",
       us.avatar AS "_avatar",
       us.banner AS "_banner",
       COUNT(DISTINCT e.id) as "_total_events",
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE g.id = 1 ) AS "_total_cs",
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE g.id = 2) AS "_total_lol"
FROM user_access."user" us JOIN
     user_access."event" e
     ON us.id = e.user_id JOIN
     user_access."game"  g
     ON e.game_id = g.id
GROUP BY us.id ;
```